# Is it possible to have mutiple test suites in TestNG?

Tags: selenium, testng

I know that we can have multiple tests in a single suite. But if I want to run more than one suite in a go, is there any way?. There were couple of questions already asked but the solution given doesn't seem to be clear.

Comment: what did you try ? what did not work for you ?

Comment: I had no clue how to do. I think the below ans. might resolve my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an XML file for each suite and after that, you can add them in testng.xml file like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="TestNG All Suites"  > 
    <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 
            <suite-files>
                   <suite-file path="./firstSuite.xml" />
                   <suite-file path="./secondSuite.xml" />
                   <suite-file path="./thirdSuite.xml" />
            </suite-files>
    </suite>
```

./ - means that the file is located in the same directory as the testng.xml file